# PHP вывод переменых из файлов на страницу

Tags: php, javascript, html

Возможно ли сделать так: имеется папка (games) со множеством страниц

и страница (site1.php), задача стоит в том чтобы вывести на страницу site1.php название и переменные всех страниц из папки (games) и отобразить всё это списком на странице site1.php, где каждой выведенной странице соответствует его переменная

p.s. я читал про то, что можно вывести только название страницы (файла) из папки, а как же получить вместе с названием и переменные, возможно ли это? Или без MySQL здесь не обойтись?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под словом "переменные" ?

Comment: В каждой странице  из папки есть несколько переменных типа "$example = 'какое-то слово, например описание' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    $cdir = scandir('папка');
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {

        if (!in_array($value, array(".", ".."))) {
            $current = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value;

            if (is_file($current)) {
                echo $value . PHP_EOL;
                echo "========================" . PHP_EOL;
                // здесь, как то тянуть переменные
                echo file_get_contents($current) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }

echo "</pre>";
```